# Entries as Flat Files

Tags: database

Is there any way to have some entries exist as flat files? Considering moving my blog over from Statamic where I have a boatload of Markdown files that work as article entries.

It seems like Craft can do anything! I wonder if there's someway to do a combo thing where some entries exist in the database and others in a directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer; no. Craft uses a database to store and query for content and doesn't have any way to work with content in files the way that Statamic has.

But, migrating the content into Craft's database doesn't have to be a big challenge.

If you're a PHP-developer, creating a plugin that parses the files and inserts the content into Craft is a breeze.

If you're not a developer (or if you are, but prefer a less code intensive way of doing it), there're several plugins for Craft that helps you importing content into the Craft database. Have a look at [Feed Me from engram design](https://github.com/engram-design/FeedMe), or [Import from Bob Olde Hampsink](https://github.com/boboldehampsink). You'd then create a simple front-end template in Statamic that queries the data you want to move over, outputs xml or json, and then send that data to the plugin which do the heavy lifting.

I've used Feed Me on several occasions to move data from ExpressionEngine sites to Craft, and it works great.